# Building a custom UIProgressVIew in XCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, progress-bar

So I'm trying to create a progress bar using the following images:
This is the background:
[image]

And this is the fill that I want to use to fill the progress bar:
[image]

Any tips on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Le documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIProgressView/trackImage)?

> > trackImage
> >     An image to use for the portion of the track that is not filled.
> >
> > @property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *trackImage
> >     Discussion
> >     If you provide a custom image, the trackTintColor property is ignored.
> >
> > Availability
> >     Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
> >     Declared In
> >     UIProgressView.h

And

> > progressTintColor
> >     The color shown for the portion of the progress bar that is filled.
> >
> > @property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *progressTintColor
> >     Availability
> >     Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
> >     Declared In
> >     UIProgressView.h

Answer (score 0):

use this function may help you. it will give image patten color which is same like image pixels. change image frame according to download progress. set this color as background of image.

```
 [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```